# Returning two RedirectToAction from controller C#.net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to return two RedirectToAction so I can render two pages if the conditions are met, or one if not. But every time I try to do this it stops at first return and ignore the other one. Is there a simple way of returning two actions from a single controller?

```
public ActionResult Create(ViewModel viewModel) {   
....    
if (supplier.Printed)
{
    return RedirectToAction("ViewDocument", "Damages", new { id = item.Id, forEmailAttachment = false });
}
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = viewModel.Id }); }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to return more than a result, mainly because to an HTTP request correspond only an HTTP response...

Comment: What you are looking for is partial views, return PartialView();
This way you can compose your html with help of razor and return a single view that will be a part of another document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to return more than one redirect. It wouldn't make sense, as one redirect would be processed right after the other, resulting in only the final redirect being effective.

If you want to incorporate two pages into one, you can use partial views.